# How do I Push to Array with Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to update a Mongo record by pushing a JSON object to an array with Node. I've gotten other `updateOne()` operators like $inc to work, but neither `$push` nor `$addToSet` are working. I don't get any errors.

`id` matches an existing document, and `payload` is valid JSON with all the appropriate fields.

Here's my updater function in Node:

```
async function arrayPusher(id, payload) {
    await client.connect()
    const db = client.db('db')
    await db.collection('collection').updateOne(
        { 'id': id }, 
        { $push: { 'post': payload } }
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough information here for us to help. What is the value of `id`? What is the value of `payload`? What is [the return value of the operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#successful-results)? Generally your command works fine - [demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IgFhHMLwXW2). Do you have a field named `id` in your documents (in addition to the mandatory `_id` field)?

Comment: Most likely value of `id` does not match any document.